# Why date column doesn't work with group by, return error Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote this query it works fine but when I add `group by Date` to it, then it returns an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 etc

My code:

```
Declare @FromDate datetime set @FromDate='2014-11-01 09:01:11.927'
Declare @ToDate datetime set @ToDate='2014-11-06 05:01:11.927'
Declare @Day int

Set @Day= (Select Count(*) from Attendance where 
  AttendanceDate >= @FromDate AND AttendanceDate < dateadd(day,1, @ToDate )
  AND Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID=47
  and organization_id=40 
  group by Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID,cast(AttendanceDate as date),User_ID
  )

  print @Day
```

Comment: So you're grouping by date and the date range you're dealing with covers (parts of) 7 days - and you're surprised that you're getting 7 results rather than 1? What did you think was going to happen here?

Comment: so what can be the solution, i need to group it

Comment: I can't answer that because I don't know *why* you think `group by` is (part of) the solution - I have neither your data nor know your *expected* results. All I've got is a query that is attempting to generate (it appears) a single number and yet is applying a `GROUP BY` clause (where adding one to an existing query can *only* result in possibly splitting a single result into multiple results)

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the original query (without grouping), it returns a number like 1337.
When you group it by date, it will return numbers that add up to the original number (1000, 300, 30, 7) and you won't be able to assign that for a variable.

If you wish to have the total number of Days, leave the group by part.

If you would like to have the results of each day, you should insert it to a temp table like

```
Select AttendanceDate, Count(*) 
from Attendance 
into #Days
where AttendanceDate >= @FromDate AND AttendanceDate < dateadd(day,1, @ToDate )
AND Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID=47
and organization_id=40 
group by Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID,cast(AttendanceDate as date),User_ID

SELECT * FROM #Days
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
Declare @FromDate datetime set @FromDate='2014-11-01 09:01:11.927'
Declare @ToDate datetime set @ToDate='2014-11-06 05:01:11.927'
Declare @Day int

Set @Day= (Select top 1 Count(*) OVER ()  from Attendance where 
  AttendanceDate >= @FromDate AND AttendanceDate < dateadd(day,1, @ToDate )
  AND Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID=47
  and organization_id=40 
  group by Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID,cast(AttendanceDate as date),User_ID
  )

  print @Day
```

Here i additionally used - top 1 Count(*) OVER ()  i.e. used to get "Count number of records returned by group by statement"

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies but none of the solutions worked for me so i tried this and worked

```
set @Day=(select count(*) from (Select  count(*) 'is' from Attendance where 
        AttendanceDate >= @FromDate AND AttendanceDate < dateadd(day,1, @ToDate )
        AND Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID=@DepartmentShiftHistory_ID
        and organization_id=@OrgID
        group by Attendance.DepartmentShiftHistory_ID,cast(AttendanceDate as date)
        ) as c)
```